# Can I get some help interpreting this code?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

So I'm working on code for school but I need some help understanding this struct and typedef that is being created

```
struct matrix_2D_struct {
    int** data_arr;
    int rows;
    int cols;
};
typedef struct matrix_2D_struct * matrix_ptr;
```

Is this defining a struct of type matrix_2D_struct which contains a pointer to a pointer of type int called data_arr, an int called rows, and an int called cols?

also I don't understand the last line. I understand it's defining something and giving it an tag of matrix_ptr, but is it defining the alias of the struct as a pointer? I'm not sure exactly how to interpret that.

also, can I define the data_arr as a 2 dimensional array using calloc?

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

some times you see some definitions like this:

```
unsigned long long var;
```

if your program has a lot of `unsigned long long` it becomes too tedious. to go over it you shorten it by defining a new type based on that using typedef, as this for example:

```
 typedef unsigned long long ULL;
```

now you just write ULL var;

same thing with struct, instead of writing each time `struct dummy var` you define a new type based on `struct dummy` using typedef like this:

```
typedef struct dummy DUMMY;

DUMMY myVar; // the type of myVar is a struct dummy
```

same way with pointer, you can define a new type that is of type  pointer , eg:

```
typedef struct dummy* P_DUMMY;

P_DUMMY myVarPtr; // the type of myVarPtr is a pointer to struct dummy;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this defining a struct of type matrix_2D_struct...

I would say a type named `matrix_2D_struct` that is a struct, rather than a struct that is a type, but otherwise yes.

> which contains a pointer to a pointer of type int called data_arr, an int called rows, and an int called cols?

Yes.

> also I don't understand the last line. I understand it's defining something and giving it an tag of matrix_ptr, but is it defining the alias of the struct as a pointer?

In C you usually pass data around as pointers. There are important reasons for this -- one, for instance, is so that you can pass structured data to a function, and the function can change the data's internals (`rows`, `cols`, even `data_arr`). Once you define a type for a struct, you usually define a type for a pointer to the struct. That's what `matrix_ptr` is. You will **probably** pass this around, instead of `matrix_2D_struct`.

> also, can I define the data_arr as a 2 dimensional array using calloc?

The question's a bit vague, but I don't see why not. I also don't see why you can't allocate the memory using `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

`matrix_ptr` is an alias of `struct matrix_2D_struct *`.

Comment: and struct matrix_2D_struct * is a pointer to a struct of type matrix_2D_struct?

Comment: @JustaRedShirt `struct matrix_2D_struct *` is a  `struct matrix_2D_struct` pointer